# Create new column conditional on time

Tags: r, dplyr

I have three columns of data (ParticipantNumber, StartTime, and Number_Readings) and I would like to create a fourth column (called Pre_Post) conditional on StartTime and Number_Readings. If Number_Readings is equal to 2, then I want the first StartTime of the day to get the label "pre" and the second StartTime of the day to get the label "post".

Data below:

```
hrv_example <- structure(list(ParticipantNumber = c("01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02"), StartTime = structure(c(1644843149, 
1644928331, 1645015129, 1645100072, 1645178623, 1645276314, 1645362165, 
1645445552, 1645533712, 1645620415, 1645705884, 1645792766, 1645879527, 
1646049708, 1646051104, 1646138403, 1646138872, 1646232054, 1646233346, 
1646310750, 1646312195, 1646400155, 1646401535, 1646655578, 1646656847, 
1646792446, 1646793770, 1646967773, 1646969041, 1647055057, 1647056414, 
1647310147, 1647311432, 1647397137, 1647398370, 1647481122, 1647482578, 
1647567549, 1647567794, 1647569031, 1647656456, 1647657722, 1647913143, 
1647914413, 1647998084, 1647999305, 1648084940, 1648086154, 1648174173, 
1648175664, 1648247400, 1648248204, 1644895927, 1645070845, 1645152649, 
1645244685, 1645329974, 1645414502, 1645499925, 1645589389, 1645680673, 
1645680882, 1645765129, 1645765337, 1645765576, 1645849869, 1645938323, 
1646106969, 1646108341, 1646197825, 1646199255, 1646285151, 1646286455, 
1646372302, 1646373657, 1646458443, 1646459728, 1646722776, 1646724075, 
1646810059, 1646810264, 1646811563, 1646887529, 1646888844, 1646984038, 
1646985328, 1647068544, 1647068749, 1647070075, 1647070280, 1647320645, 
1647321885, 1647403513, 1647404754, 1647493024, 1647494268, 1647576917, 
1647578130, 1647657670, 1647657872), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Number_Readings = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), groups = structure(list(ParticipantNumber = c("01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02"), 
    StartTime = structure(c(1644843149, 1644928331, 1645015129, 
    1645100072, 1645178623, 1645276314, 1645362165, 1645445552, 
    1645533712, 1645620415, 1645705884, 1645792766, 1645879527, 
    1646049708, 1646051104, 1646138403, 1646138872, 1646232054, 
    1646233346, 1646310750, 1646312195, 1646400155, 1646401535, 
    1646655578, 1646656847, 1646792446, 1646793770, 1646967773, 
    1646969041, 1647055057, 1647056414, 1647310147, 1647311432, 
    1647397137, 1647398370, 1647481122, 1647482578, 1647567549, 
    1647567794, 1647569031, 1647656456, 1647657722, 1647913143, 
    1647914413, 1647998084, 1647999305, 1648084940, 1648086154, 
    1648174173, 1648175664, 1648247400, 1648248204, 1644895927, 
    1645070845, 1645152649, 1645244685, 1645329974, 1645414502, 
    1645499925, 1645589389, 1645680673, 1645680882, 1645765129, 
    1645765337, 1645765576, 1645849869, 1645938323, 1646106969, 
    1646108341, 1646197825, 1646199255, 1646285151, 1646286455, 
    1646372302, 1646373657, 1646458443, 1646459728, 1646722776, 
    1646724075, 1646810059, 1646810264, 1646811563, 1646887529, 
    1646888844, 1646984038, 1646985328, 1647068544, 1647068749, 
    1647070075, 1647070280, 1647320645, 1647321885, 1647403513, 
    1647404754, 1647493024, 1647494268, 1647576917, 1647578130, 
    1647657670, 1647657872), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
        7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
        30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
        41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
        52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
        63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
        74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
        85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 
        96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried the code below, but it fails to give me the intended output.

```
hrv_example %>% 
  group_by(ParticipantNumber, StartTime) %>% 
  mutate(Pre_Post = case_when(Number_Readings == 1 ~ "single",
                              Number_Readings == 2 & StartTime == min(StartTime) ~ "pre",
                              Number_Readings == 2 & StartTime == max(StartTime) ~ "post",
                              Number_Readings == 3 | Number_Readings == 4 | Number_Readings == 5 | Number_Readings == 6 | Number_Readings ==7 ~ "multiple")) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

Comment: You are grouping your data based on date-time, but only want to group by date, 
so you might try: `hrv_example %>% group_by(ParticipantNumber, lubridate::date(StartTime)) %>% ...`

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the catch. I have a column with just the date, so I grouped by that instead of StartTime and it works how I want. Thank you!